# web.config start project from class library

Tags: iis, web-config

I tried adding

```
<configSections>
    <section name="directoryListing" type="webiste.start, website" />
</configSections>
```

example have site structure

```
/bin/mysite.dll
web.config
```

and parse all the website requests from the class library is it possible?

Comment: somehow is not working well any ideas please?

Comment: Follow a tutorial and don’t dream of anything.